# Plot 3D surface with Matplotlib a*y + b*x + c

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to Matplotlib and I need to plot a plane in a 3d graph. I have the values for a, b and c in the equation, something like `1y + 2x + 3`.

```
theta = np.array([1,2,3])
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(theta[0],theta[1],theta[2])
plt.show()
```

I know it's not the right way to use the `plot_surface()` function but I can't figure out how to.

## Update 1

I figured something out using a wireframe.

```
# Plot the plane
X = np.linspace(0,100, 500)
Y = np.linspace(0,100, 500)
Z = np.dot(theta[0],X) + np.dot(theta[1],Y) + theta[2]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z)
plt.show()
```

But it only shows a line.

[image]

Comment: Your function only has one variable, how can you draw a 3d graph from that?

Comment: I made a mistake, it would be y + 2x + 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = X + Y * 2 + 3
# Plot the surface.
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, linewidth=0)
plt.show()
```

You need to first create a meshgrid of your variables, then calculate function values on the meshgrid.

[image]